# Why does this code work, and what is the name of what is happening?

Tags: c++

I saw the following code some time ago and nobody could answer me what was, neither knew about it.
I am using Visual Studio 2010, as C++, in a file saved as cpp (at a project of win32 cmd program), then i declare the following:

```
class People {
private:
    string name;
    short age;
public:
    People (string name,short age) 
        : name(name),
          age(age) 
    {
        //
    }
    inline string getName(void) {return name;}
};

class Professor : public People {
private:
    int salary;
    int nAlunos;
public:
    Professor(string name, short age, int salary, int nAlunos) 
        : People(name,age),
          salary(salary),
          nAlunos(nAlunos) 
    {
       //
    }
};
```

Why does this assignment of the values work?

Notice that I don't write explicitly: `name = newName`, the stuff works on its own.

I also tried at wxDev-CPP and worked.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is, but perhaps you would benefit from picking up a good C++ book and learning a few of the language basics, in particular "classes and constructors"? There's no assignment; rather, it's *initialization*.

Comment: ...even with great strain I could not imagine what you're asking for. Please re-phrase your question, as it just cannot be interpreted.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is this weird colon-member syntax in the constructor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean the initialization lists?  That's where you can initialize parent classes and member variables as part of your constructor.

http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html

Answer (score 1):

```
 People (string name,short age) : name(name),age(age) {}
                               // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Constructor Initialiser List
```

Now what is `name(name)` ?

`name` in the brackets is the variable received as argument for the constructor. And the `name` before the brackets is the People class member variable. The code together is initializing argument received to the class member variable.

```
Professor(string name, short age, int salary, int nAlunos) 
    : People(name,age),
    // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Base class constructor with arguments being invoked
```

Now you need to explicitly invoke the constructor with arguments this way from derived class. In the absence of it, the compiler will call the base class default constructor ( constructor with no arguments ) and will result an error. The base class has no default constructor and compiler fails to proceed further.

Answer (score 1):

This particular code:

```
class Foo {
private:
    int value;
public:
    void Foo (int newValue) {
        value = newValue
    }
}
```

...is more or less equivalent to this code:

```
class Foo {
private:
    int value;
public:
    void Foo (int newValue) : value (newValue) {
    }
}
```

As others have pointed out, the latter is called an ["initializer list"](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html).  While in this case you could do it either way, sometimes an initializer list is required (such as initializing base classes).

One nuance is that the following would not work:

```
class Foo {
private:
    int value;
public:
    void Foo (int value) {
        value = value
        // you'd have to write this.value = value
        // otherwise it assumes both mentions of value are to the argument
    }
}
```

On the other hand, a nuance is that the initializer list method has special scoping.  It assumes that when "value" is mentioned inside the parenthesized expression, it refers to the argument...while the result is implicitly stored in the member:

```
class Foo {
private:
    int value;
public:
    void Foo (int value) : value (value) {
    }
}
```

It's a matter of taste and style as to whether you think the arguments to a constructor should have a different name than the fields they will be assigned to.  I like `newXXX`, `newYYY` style myself...just to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

It's called an initialization list and only works for Constructors.

Comment: `int a[] = {11,22,33,44,55};` **{11,22,33,44,55}** is also called initializer list.

Answer (score 0):

> Notice that i dont write explicity: "name = newName",

Yes, you do ... just in a different way.

```
 People (string name,short age) : name(name),age(age) {}
```

The constructor is initializing `name` to the `name` being passed in (same with `age`).

(As Kerrek SB points out in the comments below, there is a very big technical difference between assignment and initialization. See @adpalumbo answer for a link to the initialization list tutorial)

Comment: Those are different things. The first is assignment, the second is initialization. They're not interchangeable.

Comment: I was already editing to try and clarify that. The point I was trying to make is that there is an explicit statement that is doing what he is observing.

Comment: Brian: Hm, well, sort of. But the two are such different concepts (think of classes that are not default-constructible or that don't have an assignment operator) that I'd always want to stress that distinction.

Answer (score 0):

The following code

```
People (string arg_name, short arg_age)
    :
    name(arg_name),
    age(arg_age) 
{
    //
}
```

is equivalent to

```
People (string arg_name, short arg_age)
{
    name = arg_name;
    age = arg_age;
}
```

The difference is that the first piece of code uses an *initialization list*, in which the members of the `People` object, `name` and `age`, are constructed by *direct-initialization*, whereas `name = arg_name` *assigns* (copies) `arg_name` to **already** constructed `name` member of the object (`name` member is an object too).